# sorting a list numerically that has string and integar value

Tags: python, sorting

I am looking for a code that can sort a list say for example list x, which contains integers and string. the code would then sort the list x so that the integer value is sorted corresponding to the string. so far I have tried this code however it does not work.

```
x =["a" 2,"c" 10, "b" 5]
x.sort()
print (x)
```

I want the result to be

```
["a" 2 "b" 5 "C" 10]
```

so the list is sorted numerically in acceding order and the string is also printed.

Comment: What data type is that *list* supposed to be?

Comment: `["a" 2,"c" 10, "b" 5]` isn't valid python syntax. See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists

Comment: I am trying to associate the string to their number so a is with 2 and c is with 10

Comment: If you omit the numbers, this should work as intended.

Comment: You should read the tutorial at least as far until you've reached [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Comment: Are you sorting by the number or by the letter? It is hard to tell from your example as they are both in the same order.

Comment: @mkrieger1 A dictionary would not be suitable as there could be more of the same letters with different numbers.

Comment: @mjick you should specify your input and output lists to be valid python statements. The output list has no commas at all. Should it be a list of tuples or just a flat list?

Answer (score 1):

Use List of Tuples and then sort them according to what you want, example:

```
x = [('b',5),('a',2),('c',10)]
x.sort() # This will sort them based on item[0] of each tuple
x.sort(key=lambda s: s[1]) # This will sort them based on item[1] of each tuple
```

Another approach is to use dictionary instead of list of tuples, example:

```
x = {'b':5,'a':2,'c':10}#This will be automatically sorted based on the key of each element
```

if you print x, you will get:

```
{'a': 2, 'c': 10, 'b': 5}
```

if you want to sort them based on the value of each element, then:

```
x = sorted(x.items(), key=lambda s:s[1])
```

This will create a new list of tuples, since sorted() returns "new" sorted list, hence the result will be:

```
[('a', 2), ('b', 5), ('c', 10)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I deducted correctly you also want the resulting list to have an integer where the original list has an integer (and the same for characters).

I don't think there is an out-of-the-box way to do that. One possible approach is to separate your list into two others: one with integer, one with chars. Then, after sorting each list, you can merge them respecting the desired positions of integers and chars.

Answer (score 0):

Use a nested iterable to pair the letters to numbers, then sort the items by the second elements:

```
# just pairs.sort(key = lambda x: x[1])

pairs = [('a', 2), ('c', 10), ('b', 5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I considered the elements are separate. The following code might help, you can fill or remove the print statement in the except block, as you wish.

```
x =["a", 2,"c", 10, "b", 5]
numbers = []
letters = []
for element in x:
        try:
                numbers.append(int(element))
        except:
                letters.append(str(element))
numbers.sort()
letters.sort()
numbers.reverse()
letters.reverse()
for index,item in enumerate(x):
        try:
                print int(item),
                x[index] = numbers.pop()
        except ValueError:
                x[index] = letters.pop()
print "\n"+ str(x)
```

Comment: I got this as my result, ['a', 2, 'b', 5, 'c', 10]